# Problems with readris() when using RISparser in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using [RISparser](https://pypi.org/project/RISparser/) in Python 3 for the first time and cannot get the `readris()` function to output the bibliographic details.

Here is the updated script I am using now:

```
import os
from pprint import pprint
from RISparser import readris

filepath='C:\\Users\\mobarget\\Google Drive\\RIS_export_PolishNationalLibrary'

for f in os.listdir(filepath): # define filepath as directory containing iterable files
    print(f) # returns correct file names, e.g. Primo_RIS_Export.ris
    f_path=os.path.join(filepath, f)
    with open(f_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as bibliography_file:
        
        print(bibliography_file)
# OUTPUT: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\mobarget\\Google Drive\\RIS_export_PolishNationalLibrary\\Primo_RIS_Export(12).ris' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>
    
        entries=readris(bibliography_file)
        print(entries)
        
# OUTPUT: <generator object Base.parse at 0x000001E2840E29A8>       
        for entry in entries:
            print(entry['id']) # select entry according to tag-key-mapping
            print(entry['primary_title']) # select entry according to tag-key-mapping
```

As you can see in the comments, `readris()` returns some generator object information but not the content of the file. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Did you try to iterate the generator to get the results?

Comment: The function I used was adapted directly from the original documentation, but the whole RISparser package has been updated. See my answer below. It's all working great with the new ```rispy()``` function.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the developer on GITHUB and found out that the RISparser package is outdated:

> That's correct. RISparser was version 0.4 and below, and we renamed
> and rebranded to rispy in version 0.5. The API for rispy is much
> cleaner and mirrors the python json library from the stdlib, which
> many people are familiar with.
>
> For more details, read the changelog:
> https://github.com/MrTango/rispy/blob/master/HISTORY.rst#v05-2020-02-21

This code is working:

```
# Please note that rispy is the follow-up version of RISparser
# download and documentation: https://pypi.org/project/rispy/

import os
from pprint import pprint
import rispy

# define file path for local RIS files
filepath='C:\\Users\\mobarget\\Google Drive\\RIS_export_PolishNationalLibrary'

# define filepath as directory containing iterable files

for f in os.listdir(filepath): 
    print(f) # return file names, e.g. Primo_RIS_Export.ris
    f_path=os.path.join(filepath, f)
    with open(f_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as bibliography_file:      
        print(bibliography_file)
        
        entries=rispy.load(bibliography_file)
                  
        for entry in entries:
            print(entry['primary_title'])
```